# Spring Unit Test and object re-injection

Tags: spring, unit-testing

In Spring what is the best way to run a bunch of test methods on an object but reset/re-inject the object before each new test method invocation?
I have tried to do in the code below but with my current logic the object gets created and injected only once..

```
package com.bidtracker;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

import com.bidtracker.iface.BidTracker;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BidTrackerTest {

    @Autowired
    BidTracker tracker;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHighestBidAmount1(){

    tracker.bidOnItem("itemB", "user1", 105);
    assertThat(tracker.getHighestBid("itemB").getAmount(),is(Integer.valueOf(105)));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHighestBidAmount2(){

    tracker.bidOnItem("itemB", "user1", 39); 
    tracker.bidOnItem("itemB", "user1", 50); 

    assertThat(tracker.getHighestBid("itemB").getAmount(),is(Integer.valueOf(50)));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Spring test support by default caches the application context and will reuse the cached context if elements of the key match up(context name(s), active profiles etc). To ask Spring to remove the context from the cache you can mark the test with `@DirtiesContext` annotation (at the method level or test class level).

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem.  I'm curious however, does Spring consider this kind of test formulation bad (.. dirty)?

Comment: I think it is okay, thing is creating an application context from scratch is costly and that is the reason why Spring test tends to cache it across tests (if there were multiple test classes in a suite using the same context, it would be reused across the suite). However if there is a absolute need to recreate the context, the option of @DirtiesContext is always there :-)

Answer (score 1):

JUnit has the [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) annotation, you can use that to do any initialization before each test.

However, I am curious about your case. Here's from the `@Test` documentation:

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which
>   it is attached can be run as a test case. To run the method, JUnit
>   first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the
>   annotated method. Any exceptions thrown by the test will be reported
>   by JUnit as a failure. If no exceptions are thrown, the test is
>   assumed to have succeeded.

I'm guessing that the issue is that the bean is a singleton. It actually gets injected again, but if it's been modified you're using the same thing. You can try the [@DirtiesContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) annotation.

Comment: I prefer not to clone this object.  I prefer to recreate/re-inject the object at each invocation